# How to convert XML to Json in XSLT?

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

How to convert xml to json in xslt

input xml:

```
<root>
    <citiID>RR1</citiID>
    <bib>ertyokf (5208). Free <Emphasis Type="Italic">of detachment</Emphasis>, aedrtg. dcdcdr<b>49</b> any text</bib>
</root>
```

expected Json:

```
  "root": [
    {
        "citeid": "RR1",
        "bib": "ertyokf (5208). Free <Emphasis Type=\"Italic\">of detachment</Emphasis>, aedrtg. dcdcdr<b>49</b> any text."
    },
    ]
```

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two approaches, one is a direct representation of your desired JSON as XDM 3.1 maps and arrays:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">


  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="map {
        local-name() : array {
          map:merge(* ! map {
            lower-case(local-name()) : serialize(node())
          })
        }
      }"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZYrpR/1

The second would be to transform your input XML into the XML representation of JSON the `xml-to-json` function uses.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the xml-to-json() function in XSLT 3.0 isn't designed to handle arbitrary XML, it's only designed to handle the "XML representation of JSON" produced by the json-to-xml() function.

You have two options: either transform your XML to a structure of maps and arrays and then serialize this as JSON, or transform it to the XML vocabulary that xml-to-json() accepts.

(The reason for this is well illustrated by your example, where you are trying to keep some of the elements represented as markup. No off-the-shelf conversion is going to do that for you.)

Also note: your expected output isn't JSON. It needs surrounding curly braces to make it JSON: there's also a stray comma that needs fixing.

I would do:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:variable name="temp" as="map(*)" select="
     map{ "root": [
        map{ "citeID": string(citiID (:sic:)),
             "bib": serialize(bib/child::node(), map{"method":"xml", "omit-xml-declaration": true()}
        }]}"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="serialize($temp, map{"method":"json", "indent":true()})"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Not tested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xslt3 there is a function for it,xml-to-json ()

This is explained here:
[Using XSLT 3.0 to transform XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334578/using-xslt-3-0-to-transform-xml)

It can be done in xslt1 and 2 as well, but the approach is different - which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks Bryn. In after xsl transformation my output be : **"root": [
   { "citiID" : "RR1",
  "bib" : "ertyokf (5208). Free of detachment, aedrtg. dcdcdr49 (2), 4185–428553. 1991. In india." 
 }
    ]** After conversion, a, emphasis, b are missing in bib tag. Any idea for this scenario

Comment: version XSLT 3.0