# Transform XML to JSON using xslt

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I would like to use XSLT to transform some XML into JSON.

*The XML looks like the following:*

```
<root>
 <item>
   <number>123</number>
   <name>ABC</name>
   <EmployeeCode>
   <id>11</id>
   <Department>
         <Name>Zing</Name>
         <Age>42</Age>
         <Designation>Engineer</Designation>
    </Department>
    <Status>Contractor</Status>
   </EmployeeCode>
```

*Expecting  like below*

```
<root>
 <item>
    <number>123</number>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <EmployeeCode>
        <id>11</id>
        "Department": {"Name": "Zing","Age": "42","Designation": "Engineer"}
        <Status>Contractor</Status>
    </EmployeeCode>
</item>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version, which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? With XSLT 3 it is easier than in previous versions to do it in a short and robust way.

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you. Also, in all your questions regarding XSLT please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: why don't you try wildcard on department/* and in for loop consider generating json string.

Comment: Looking closer it also is not quite clear at which point you want or have JSON in the output, the part with `"Department" : ` doesn't look like quite like JSON.

Comment: I want to convert the Department structure into Json formate, the Main Structure should be in XML only,

Comment: XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 allows you to create JSON and serialize to JSON with two approaches, either by transforming your XML to the format the `xml-to-json` function expects or by using the `serialize` function with `method` being `json` on XPath 3.1 maps/arrays you create from the XML you have.

Comment: can you provide an example, please..

Comment: You will first need to tell or decide whether you can use XSLT 3 with e.g. Saxon 10 or Saxon-JS 2 or Altova XML. As for examples, reading https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json helps, as should https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#maps-and-arrays. Then look at similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927952/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-xslt/62931081#62931081 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947872/xslt-3-0-json-to-xml-and-xml-to-json-conversion.